# Drawing a line with hidden parts in cocos2d for ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Say you have an array of points and an array of rects, and you want to do the following:

Draw a line that connects all the points in the point array, such that the parts of the line that are contained in at least one of the rects are not visible.

What is the best practice way to accomplish such a task in cocos2d ios?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a hack, but if you are drawing the rectangles as well then you can draw them with a higher zOrder with respect to the line and the rectangles would could cover the parts of the lines they contain making those parts invisible.
Hope it helps!